# NSPredicate nested Array with custom objects

Tags: ios, nspredicate, nsobject

```
@interface Product : NSObject
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* productID;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* productName;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* productImageURL;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* price;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* categoryID;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* categoryName;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* isSelected;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger quantity;
@end


@interface ProductCategory : NSObject
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* categoryID;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* categoryName;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* isSelected;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray* productsArray;
@end
```

i have an array of product categories which have productsArray of product Objects, now i need to filter products whose quantity is > 0 using NSPredicate, i tried using ANY but its not accurate.

Comment: Show your tried with Any.

Comment: NSPredicate* selectedProductsPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY productsArray.quantity.intValue >0"];

Comment: i got the desired result with a for loop,i was just wondering if it can be done directly using nspredicate     for (NSInteger i=0; i<contentArray.count; i++) {
        ProductCategory * tempCategory=[contentArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSPredicate* selectedProductsPredicate=[NSPredicate   predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.quantity.intValue >0"];
        NSMutableArray * tempArray=[[tempCategory.productsArray   filteredArrayUsingPredicate:selectedProductsPredicate] mutableCopy];
        if (tempArray.count>0) {
            [updatedProductsArray addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
        }
    }